# tastypie won't remove foreignkey reference during PUT

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm having an issue with Tastypie not saving changes to my object when I do a PUT that causes a foreignkey field to be set to null.

Here's my ModelResource:

```
class FolderResource(ModelResource):
    parent = fields.ForeignKey('self','parent',full=True,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    project = fields.ForeignKey(ProjectResource,'project',full=False)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Folder.objects.all()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'folder'
        include_absolute_url = True
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            "slug": ('exact', 'startswith',),
            "name": ALL,
            "project":ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            "parent":ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            "id":('exact')
            }
```

I have an existing folder object with the following data:

```
{
    absolute_url: "/projects/1/files/5/",
    created_date: "13 Feb 2012",
    id: "5",
    modified_date: "15 Feb 2012",
    modified_file: null,
    name: "testfolder2",
    parent: {
        absolute_url: "/projects/1/files/1/",
        created_date: "4 Feb 2012",
        id: "1",
        modified_date: "15 Feb 2012",
        modified_file: null,
        name: "testfolder1",
        parent: null,
        project: "/projects/api/v1/project/1/",
        removed_date: null,
        resource_uri: "/projects/api/v1/folder/1/",
        slug: "testfolder1"
    },
    project: "/projects/api/v1/project/1/",
    removed_date: null,
    resource_uri: "/projects/api/v1/folder/5/",
    slug: "testfolder2"
}
```

I will try to PUT the following data to '/projects/api/v1/folder/5/':

```
{
    parent: null
}
```

I don't get back any errors, everything seems fine but nothing gets saved to the database. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or why the change isn't being saved?

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Same here... Using NamespacedModelResource btw. Can't get it to work, while using PATCH. parent: null in this example just makes an empty parent :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a partial update, then you need a PATCH method.